# How to feed bytecode to python interpreter from stdin?

Tags: python, bytecode

I know I can run a python script from stdin like this:

```
python - < script.py
```

I also can run a compiled python file:

```
python script.pyc
```

But I can't run a compiled python file from stdin:

```
python - < script.pyc
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xee' in file <stdin> on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Clearly I have to tell the interpreter that this is bytecode. But how?

Comment: For future visitors to this question, the accepted answer is incorrect. It is in fact possible. See the answer below for further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bytecode should no be passed as standard input. It contains executable code which is run only by the pyhon interpreter and outside it, it is just gibberish. Basically when you are trying to pass the file as stdin it is treated as text and therefore the error you get. .py file is in text format therefore it can be safely parse like a text and properly executed.

From your code example I will assume you are trying to run the file from a bash console (line in Linux) so the correct way is indeed:

```
python script.pyc
```

which is what you also tried.

Comment: So the answer is: It is just not possible with stdin?

Comment: I thinks so. Bycode has no meaning when interpreted as text.

Answer (score 3):

**TL/DR**

It's possible with

```
python -c "import sys;import marshal;exec(marshal.loads(sys.stdin.buffer.read()[16:]))" < script.pyc
```

**Long version**

The previous answer is incorrect. It is possible to achieve this via stdin.
The Python interpreter has a -c flag that allows it to interpret code.
For example,

```
python -c "print('Hello, world!')"
```

will output `Hello, world!`
Standard input can be read in a python program using the builtin library `sys`, specifically the `sys.stdin.buffer.read()` function. This can only be read once, though, and returns a bytes-like object.

`.pyc` files have a special structure - 4 magic bytes, a timestamp, and a marshalled code object.
Together, the magic bytes and the timestamp are 16 bytes. From what I've found, the timestamp doesn't matter, but the magic bytes change between versions. Removing this, we have a marshalled code object. That's what the `[16:]` does - removing the magic bytes and the timestamp from the bytes-like object in standard input.

Python uses the `marshal` library to compress the code object that results from compilation, and provides the `marshal.loads(bytes)` function to convert the bytes-like object into the unmarshalled object, which is in this case an instance of `types.CodeType` - a code object.

Finally, while Python's `exec()` function normally takes a string, it also can take a code object. We pass it the code object, and it executes it.

**A word of warning:**
Passing bytecode directly to standard input and then executing is a huge security issue and poor practice, but given that you're trying this in the first place, you probably don't care.

**References:**

[sys — System-specific parameters and functions — Python 3.9.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin)

[The structure of .pyc files | Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200804/the_structure_of_pyc_files.html)

[Built-in Types — Python 3.9.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects)

[marshal — Internal Python object serialization — Python 3.9.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html#marshal.loads)

[Built-in Functions — Python 3.9.6 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)